# Как исправить, чтобы в телеграмм, прошлая клавиатура не копировалась при повторной отправке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

Я делаю бота в телеграмме, на Питоне с использованием библиотеки aiogram.

Во время работы с клавиатурой, столкнулся с проблемой и не могу найти решение. Проблема заключается в том, что у меня стоит реакция на определенное сообщение, после которого - отправляется клавиатура. Потом, при нажатии на эту клавиатуру, на данный момент, мне нужно чтобы она скрывалась. Процесс скрытия заключается в том, чтобы отправить пустую клавиатуру. Всё успешно, однако, после 2 попытки отправить клавиатуру на эту же команду, получается так, что клавиатура "копируется" и в итоге, у меня уже не 2 кнопки как должно быть, а 4. Помогите пожалуйста решить данную проблему.
Фото:

[Фото3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIEvz.jpg)

[Фото2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IzDA.jpg)

[Фото1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlKtz.jpg)

Часть того кода:

```
elif userAct == "joing":
   if msgr == str(dsert[0]):
       
       print("yes1")
       dbs.dt.update_users_act(id, "newUser") #изменение статуса пользователя в бд
       await msg.reply("es", reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
   elif msgr == str(dsert[1]):
       print("yes2")
       dbs.dt.update_users_act(id, "newUser")
       await msg.reply("es", reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
   else:
       print("yes3")
       dbs.dt.update_users_act(id, "newUser")
       await msg.reply("es", reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
```

Answer (score 0):

При отправке кнопок вы можете добавить опцию one_time_keyboard=True, которое скроет кнопки после нажатия.
Почитайте об этом [здесь](https://surik00.gitbooks.io/aiogram-lessons/content/chapter5.html)

Comment: Не помогает. Прошлая клавиатура остаётся даже при отправке новой, не пустой. P.s. я добавляю параметры клавиатуры(текст) из массива, может в этом причина?

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте вначале список:

```
black_users = []
```

В функции обработчика нажатий кнопки запишите:

```
global black_users
if ID юзера not in black_users:
    #код действий по нажатию кнопки
    black_users.append(ID юзера)
```

Такой код сойдёт даже на многопользовательского бота (в отличие от другого ответа).

**P. S. с `aiogram` работал мало, поэтому я не знаю, как вызвать ID юзера и заменяю русской фразой. Замените это на функцию получения ID юзера**